# Virtual Port Forwarding for Device Web Server

Tags: port-forwarding, remote-access, nat

I've got a streaming device, where I've set the port for the webserver to let's say 3030 and I configured the router as follows:

```
service name: some service 
Port range: 3030 
IP Address: 192.168.1.80
Local Port: 3030
Protocol: Both
```

Yet I'm not able to remote Access the web server, using the public address, for the given device. I know I'm probably missing something simple, but any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more details so people can better help you.

- What is your network topology (modem, router, machine connections)?
- Did you configure firewalls (router, machines, etc) to allow the necessary ports access in & out?
- Did you test an internal (LAN) forwarding to access server before trying external?
- What are the errors receiving & what fixes have you tried?
- Are there other specific network info /configuration regarding the server / router that might be helpful to better diagnose the problem you need to share?